# windows timer vba change speed

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, timer

I'm using the windows timer API within VBA to proc a sub every 0.5s. I want to be able to change the timerproc speed while the timer is running. Unfortunately the StartTimer sub is only called once at the beginning. Any ideas on how I can modify my code to change speeds (say to 0.25s)?

```
Public Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
    ByVal uElapse As Long, _
    ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Public TimerID As Long
Public TimerSeconds As Single

Sub stopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    KillTimer 0&, TimerID
End Sub
Sub StartTimer()
    RerunSpeed = 0.5
    TimerSeconds = RerunSpeed
    TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, TimerSeconds * 1000&, AddressOf TimerProc)
End Sub


Sub TimerProc(ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
        ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal dwTimer As Long)

    Call RecalculateData

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the following modifications to your code.

```
Public TimerID As Long
Public TimerSeconds As Single
Public TimerRunning As Boolean

Sub stopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    KillTimer 0&, TimerID
    TimerRunning = False
End Sub

Sub StartTimer(Optional RerunSpeed As Double = 0.5)
    If TimerRunning Then stopTimer
    TimerSeconds = RerunSpeed
    TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, TimerSeconds * 1000&, AddressOf TimerProc)
    TimerRunning = True
End Sub
```

You can make subsequent calls to the `StartTimer` sub procedure with alternate time intervals. If the timer is currently active, it will be halted and reinstated with a new interval; e.g. `StartTimer 0.25`

Answer (score 2):

The timer interval is specified once and for all when you create the timer by calling `SetTimer`. If you need to modify the interval, you need to re-create the timer by calling `KillTimer` first, and then `SetTimer` with the new interval.